# Spark 3.2 parsing INI file using apache commons library is not working properly

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, apache-commons-configuration

Spark 3.1:

INI

```
[medium]
tablelist="Test1,Test2,Test3"

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalINIConfiguration
val env_config_ini = s"/file_path/config.ini".toLowerCase
val configobject = new HierarchicalINIConfiguration(env_config_ini)
var globalconfigvariable = configobject.getSection("medium")
var tablist = globalconfigvariable.getString("tablelist")
```

output:
tablist: String = Test1,Test2,Test3

Spark 3.2.1:

INI

```
[medium]
tablelist="Test1,Test2,Test3"


import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalINIConfiguration
val env_config_ini = s"/file_path/config.ini".toLowerCase
val configobject = new HierarchicalINIConfiguration(env_config_ini)
var globalconfigvariable = configobject.getSection("medium")
var tablist = globalconfigvariable.getString("tablelist")
```

output:
tablist: String = Test1

After migrating to spark3.2.1 when i run the same code its returning first element comma separated values defined in INI

Tried with all version of spark3.2.x and commons-configuration and its same issue where as in spark3.1 it works fine